# Maven dependencies for Gson not being downloaded

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, gson

I'm not that familiar with using Maven, so it is likely a user error in this case.  My understanding of the  elements in the POM file is that any "dependency" that is listed here will be retrieved from the Central Repository based upon the scope of the dependency.  In my case, I'm attempting to use the Gson library from Google.  It is located on the Central Repository and so it should be reachable by the Maven tool.  I've executed "mvn -X compile" to determine if I can see the dependencies in the import. But I don't see them being downloaded during the compile.  Any ideas as to what could be wrong with my configuration?

Below is my POM for my project.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.acumen.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>CatalogConverter</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>CatalogConverter</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: maven will only download the library if it hasn't already previously downloaded it.  Check your .m2 directory and see if you've already got gson.

Comment: Ha!  It must have already downloaded.  Now....to just have my application import statement recognize this.